# Como girar uma img 90º ocupando 100% do elemento?

Tags: css

Tenho a seguinte imagem para exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A linha em preto é o container da pagina(mobile) e a em vermelho a imagem,
No exemplo 1 é o que tenho hoje, e o 2 o resultado que estou tentando chegar,
não estou conseguindo achar uma solução sem distorcer a imagem, exite alguma forma?

segue código:

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.container {
  background-color: #bbb;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/na/us/credit/hub/prepaid-image.png?01AD=3tN7YRjc7dW4pgCz6srp1Zwrd3T603duDiW7xKKoinH54ISdhxQdalQ&01RI=BDC70922D249C25&01NA="/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Opção 1**

Vc pode usar `object-fit: contain` na imagem. 
*(essa opção não funciona no IE como vc pode consultar aqui: https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)*

Veja como fica:

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.35);
  object-fit: contain;
}

.container {
  background-color: #bbb;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/na/us/credit/hub/prepaid-image.png?01AD=3tN7YRjc7dW4pgCz6srp1Zwrd3T603duDiW7xKKoinH54ISdhxQdalQ&01RI=BDC70922D249C25&01NA="/>
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2 usando a imagem como background.**

Essa opção funciona no IE, mas a imagem tem que ser um `Background` do *container*, vc pode consultar o suporte dos browsers aqui: https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

```css
.container {
  background-color: #bbb;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.container::after {
    content: "";
    top: 15px;
    left: -55px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 410px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-image: url(https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/na/us/credit/hub/prepaid-image.png?01AD=3tN7YRjc7dW4pgCz6srp1Zwrd3T603duDiW7xKKoinH54ISdhxQdalQ&01RI=BDC70922D249C25&01NA=);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Interessante, chega muito perto do que eu gostaria, mas será que não tem como deixar a imagem o mais próximo possível do tamanho da tela?

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno tem como sim, repare no segundo exemplo que eu editei o código, ajustando o heigh e o width, e o left e top vc consegue chegar bem próximo do tamanho do container.

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno cara ajustei tb a primeira opção, nela eu usei um scale(1.35) para fazer a imagem ocupar mais espaço no container